# Why escaping double quote with single and triple backslashes in a Java regular expression yields identical results

Tags: java, regex

I want to escape `"` (double quotes) in a regex.

I found out that there is no difference whether I use `\\\` or `\`, both yield the same correct result.

Why is it so? How can the first one give correct result?

Comment: If I was to guess, I'd say Java uses the first two to treat the third as a literal character, and the regexp uses that third one to do what it needs with it. But the regexp could just use the singular one by itself either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a `"` char in a string literal in Java, you need to escape it for the string parsing engine, like `"\""`.

The `"` char is *not* a special regex metacharacter, so you needn't escape this character *for the regex engine*. However, [you *may* do it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct.

To define a regex escape a literal backslash is used, and it is defined with double backslash in a Java string literal, `"\\"`:

> It is therefore necessary to double backslashes in string literals that represent regular expressions to protect them from interpretation by the Java bytecode compiler.

So, both `"\""` (a literal `"` string) and `"\\\""` (a literal `\"` string) form a regex pattern that matches a single `"` char.

Comment: Thanks, Sir it really helped

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
String regex = "(\"\\w+\")";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Some \"test\" string. And \"another\" quoted word.");

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Prints:

```
"test"
"another"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I know this but it doesn't answered my question, please read it once again.