# Regular Expressions with double backslash in java

Tags: java, string

I want to understand the concept of regular expression in below code:

```
private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO ${table}(${keys}) 
VALUES(${values})";
private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";
.
.
.
String query = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, "tableName");
```

The above code is working fine but i would like to understand how. As per my knowledge $ and { symbols should be escaped in java string using backslash but in above string there is no backslash and if I try to add it, it shows error: invalid escape sequence.

Also why the `TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";` contains double backslash?

Comment: The backslash itself needs to be escaped: the content of your string is `\$\{table\}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$` and `{` don't need to be escaped in Java string literals in general but in regular expressions they need to be escaped as they have special meaning in regular expressions. The `$` matches the end of a line and `{` is used for matching characters a certain amount of times. To match any of the regular expression special characters themselves these characters need to be escaped. For example `A{5}` matches `AAAAA` but `A\{5` matches `A{5`.

To escape something in a regular expression string you use the `\`. But the backslash in string literals itself needs escaping which is done by another `\`. That is the String literal `"\\{"` actually corresponds to the string `"\{"`.

This is why in regular expression string literals you will often encounter multiple backslashes. You might also want to take a look at [`Pattern.quote(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) which takes a string and properly escapes all special characters (wrt. Java regular expressions).

Essentially instead of

```
private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";
```

you could write

```
private static final String TABLE_REGEX = Pattern.quote("${table}");
```

In your example `SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, "tableName");` matches the first occurrence of `${table}` in `SQL_INSERT` and replaces this occurrence with `tableName`:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ${table}(${keys}) VALUES(${values})".replaceFirst("\\$\\{table\\}", "tableName");
boolean test = sql.equals("INSERT INTO tableName(${keys}) VALUES(${values})");
System.out.println(test); // will print 'true'
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I would like to understand one more thing.


`private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO table(keys) VALUES(values)";
 private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "table"; `
 

the above code will also give the same result then what is the need of ${.
I got your point on A{5} but what is its need in above code?

Comment: @LovishJain in your code `${table}` seems to be used as placeholder. `${xyz}` is a quite common notation in templates for strings that will be replaced by the actual value of some property `xyz`. However, as you already noticed, in your example it doesn't make much sense as `${table}` is always replaced with the static string `tableName`. It would make more sense if instead of always using `"tableName"` as replacement a variable or parameter would be used.

Comment: ok..got that point. sorry if it sounds silly but since both strings are declared in same way `private static final String` and both include ${ then how it considers second string as regex and not a static string and works differently.

Comment: @LovishJain, you're welcome. That's because of how [`String.replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) interprets the first argument. `"${test}".replaceFirst("\\$\\{test\\}", "success")` is essentially the same as `Pattern.compile("\\$\\{test\\}").matcher("${test}").replaceFirst("success")`

Comment: oh... the syntax accepts first argument as regex. don't know how i skipped it. Thanks @dpr for answering

Answer (score 5):

`$` or `"$"` is the dollar sign / a string containg it.
`\$` is an escaped dollar sign, normally found in *raw* regex if you want to match the char $ instead of the end of the line
`"\\$"` is a String containing an escaped `\` followed by a normale `$`. Since you are not writing a *raw* regex, but the regex is inside a Java `String` you need to escape the `\` so that when the regex interpreter comes along it just sees a normal `\` which it then treats as escaping the following `$`.

`"\$"` is not valid because from a normal `String` point of view a `$` is nothing special and does not need to / must not be escaped.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057519/4982691

Answer (score 1):

> i would like to understand how.

It is replacing the first match of the regex `"\\$\\{table\\}"` in the original string  `"INSERT INTO ${table}(${keys}) VALUES(${values})"` with `"tableName"`.

> $ and { symbols should be escaped in java string
>   using backslash but in above string there is no backslash and if I try
>   to add it, it shows error: invalid escape sequence.

No, `${}` are not escaped in a Java string, why would they?

> Also why the TABLE_REGEX = "\$\{table\}"; contains double
>   backslash?

In Java escaping is done by double backslash because single backslash indicates special character (e.g. `\n`, `\t`). It is escaping `${}` symbols because these symbols have a special meaning in a regex, so escaping them tells the Java regex engine to treat them literally as those symbols and not their special meaning.