# Scanner construction fails because FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

The following piece of code gts a directory and if there is a file in it, that is called "Tabelle.csv" a scanner should be created and show its contents.

```
if (folder.isDirectory()){
            File[] files = folder.listFiles();
            
            String ta = "Tabelle.csv";
            
            for (File file: files){
                if (file.exists()){
                    if (file.getName().equals(ta)){

                        System.out.println("PATH: " + file);
                        //*
                        Scanner sc = new Scanner (file);
                        sc.useDelimiter(";");
                        while(sc.hasNext()){
                            System.out.println(sc.next());
                        }
                        sc.close();//*/

                    }
                } 
            }
        }
```

This however throws a FileNotFoundExcepion, which baffles me, since i doublecheked for its existence with both ifs.

Please help me with as easily understandable solutions as possible, since I am still learning.
Thanks in advance :D

ChatGPT told be to do that:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(fis);
```

which also ended up in the same error, but in the FIS construction.

I also dont want a trycatch, since this NEEDS to work, I dont care about the console telling me: "File does not exist" or something

edit:

I started with 'Scanner sc = new Scanner(THEACTUALPATH);' but that got me the error, so I am backwards engineering from there. This is also the reason for the outer if. I know it is meaningless, but its kind of a sanity check that the file is there... I dont know why I am getting the error, and how to avoid it

Comment: The outer `if` is meaningless and should be deleted. If iteration is occurring at all, it's going to return true for every file in that folder. Your code assumes that your sought file should be in that directory *and not a subdirectory*. It seems rather odd to be searching at all tbh, but to be complete, you need to recurse. A lot easier to use `Files.find`

Comment: Or just `new File(folder, "Tabelle.csv").isFile()`

Comment: I am unable to duplicate the problem.  Make sure you're running this code and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the folder path you specified here...

**if (folder.isDirectory()){
}**

did you correctly put the path into the File constructor using escape sequence?
like this...

File folder=new File(**"C:\\Parent folder\\child folder"**);

***use double  slash \\ to separate folders or files if you are in windows.***

Just check that out.

**Put your scanner creation into try catch block to handle error.**

and clear the   **if (file.exists()){** block because listfiles already gives you the list of files and directories that exists if you are looking for a simple way to filter out only files just use **if(!file.isDirectory())** inspite of **file.exists()** and this will give you a condition to run the code only with files you can also use **if(!file.isDirectory() && file.getName().equals(ta))** to kill two birds with one stone...first the code will check if your file is a file and then go for the fact if the name matches...

Hope it helps buddy.

your new code should look like this.

```
   if (folder.isDirectory()){
                File[] files = folder.listFiles();
                
                String ta = "Tabelle.csv";
                
                for (File file: files){

                    if (file.isDirectory() && file.getName().equals(ta)){
                           
                            System.out.println("PATH: " + file);
                            //*

                          try{

                            Scanner sc = new Scanner (file);
                            sc.useDelimiter(";");

                            while(sc.hasNext()){
                                System.out.println(sc.next());
                            }
                            sc.close();//*/

                            }catch(Exception error){

                            System.out.println("Error occurred! Reason>>>"+error);
                               }
       
                              }
         
                          }
             
                        
                    }
```

Comment: *use double slash // to separate folders or files if you are in windows.* A single forward slash will suffice for any OS

Comment: _"into the File constructor using escape sequence?"_ — The escape character is **back**-slash ('\'), not a (forward) slash (`/`). Using _backslashes_ in windows is when they need to be doubled, because you need to escape the _escape character_. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057519/17300) about regex explains it pretty well.

Comment: Hey Stephen Thanks for mentioning that buddy.I made my correction.The mistake was made as I was really too focused on the output path address on my computer.

Comment: Hey @g00se thanks for a better suggestion.Both works.I was just suggesting the traditional way.